# iOS HMScanKit not work at iOS 17.0, can not start scan

Tags: ios

we use hmscankit in iOS App, now can not restart scan service in iOS 17.0, all scanView is black, can anyone help me. we use the framework in lower version successfully, i dont know where is the problem now.

we want to use the hmScankit in iOS 17.0